# How to get IP Address from url without gethostbyname in Winsock API

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, ip-address, winsock

I want to get IP Address from URL. I find the answer in google, it only has `gethostbyname()` function solution, but MSDN said that this function is not used anymore.

I try to use `getaddressinfo()` or `getnameinfo()` (the example in MSDN), it only returns 255.255.255.255.

How can I do? Thank all!

Comment: More context recommended. There are many cases where you could have a result like this that will have nothing to do with your case.

Comment: now I want to get IP address, using winsock or not but must use C++, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyname()` is indeed deprecated, and [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) is the correct function to use now.

You need to *parse* the URL to extract its hostname, and optionally its port number (see [`InternetCrackUrl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcrackurla), or other similar parser), then pass that hostname/port to `getaddrinfo()`.  It will give you back a linked list of `addrinfo` structs containing each IP address assigned to the host, in `sockaddr_in` (IPv4) or `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6) format.

If you need those IPs as strings, you can use [`inet_ntop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop), [`RtlIpv4AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv4addresstostringa)/[`RtlIpv6AddressToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6addresstostringa), [`getnameinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getnameinfo) with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are obtained by domain name, not by URL.

Here are two functions to get an IPv6 and IPv4 address from a domain name.

Functions parameter is domain_name - domain name (eg dns.google).
The result is local_internet_name - a list of IPv6 or IPv4 addresses depending on the function used (e.g. {[8.8.8.8], [8.8.4.4]} for IPv4 addresses of the dns.google domain)
The return value is the attribute "Addresses found or not found" (true and false).

domain_name_to_internet_6_name

domain_name_to_internet_4_name

The functions use the MFC string classes, the C++ standard library, Windows DNS functions, and network functions.

An example of the output from a test console program:

2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4

D:\Projects\DNS_Test\Debug\DNS_Test.exe (process 14740) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .

To create an executable for Windows, in Microsoft Visual Studio, you need to create a project from the "Console Application for Windows" template, and set the project properties to "Use MFC library" (as a shared library or as a static library)

Here's the code for a console program:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "normaliz.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dnsapi.lib")

bool domain_name_to_internet_6_name(CStringW domain_name, std::list<CStringA>& local_internet_name)
{
  const size_t CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 500;

  wchar_t local_domain_name_unicode[CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

  ZeroMemory(local_domain_name_unicode, sizeof(wchar_t) * CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

  if (IdnToAscii(0, domain_name, domain_name.GetLength(), local_domain_name_unicode, CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH) == 0)
  {
    const int local_error_message_size = 500;
    wchar_t local_error_message[local_error_message_size];

    const int local_system_error_message_size = local_error_message_size - 250;
    wchar_t local_system_error_message[local_system_error_message_size];

    wcscpy_s(local_system_error_message, local_system_error_message_size, L"IdnToAscii finished with error");

    CString local_time_string = CTime::GetCurrentTime().FormatGmt("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S GMT");

    wsprintf((wchar_t*)local_error_message, L"Networking error -- %s -- %s\r\n", local_system_error_message, local_time_string.GetBuffer());

    //  В local_error_message находится текст с кодом сетевой ошибки при выполнении функции IdnToAscii

    return false;
  }


  PDNS_RECORD   ppQueryResults;

  ZeroMemory(&ppQueryResults, sizeof(ppQueryResults));

  if (DnsQuery_W(local_domain_name_unicode, DNS_TYPE_AAAA, 0, NULL, &ppQueryResults, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    for (PDNS_RECORD ptr = ppQueryResults; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->pNext)
    {
      if (ptr->wType == DNS_TYPE_AAAA)
      {
        if (ptr->wDataLength != 0)
        {
          char local_address_buffer[100];
          inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ptr->Data.AAAA.Ip6Address.IP6Byte, local_address_buffer, 100);

          local_internet_name.push_back(local_address_buffer);
        }
      }
    }

    DnsFree(ppQueryResults, DnsFreeRecordList);

    if (local_internet_name.size() != 0)
    {
      return true;  //  Адреса найдены
    }
    else
    {
      return false; //  Адреса не найдены
    }

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

bool domain_name_to_internet_4_name(CStringW domain_name, std::list<CStringA>& local_internet_name)
{
  const size_t CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 500;

  wchar_t local_domain_name_unicode[CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

  ZeroMemory(local_domain_name_unicode, sizeof(wchar_t) * CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

  if (IdnToAscii(0, domain_name, domain_name.GetLength(), local_domain_name_unicode, CONST_MESSAGE_LENGTH) == 0)
  {
    const int local_error_message_size = 500;
    wchar_t local_error_message[local_error_message_size];

    const int local_system_error_message_size = local_error_message_size - 250;
    wchar_t local_system_error_message[local_system_error_message_size];

    wcscpy_s(local_system_error_message, local_system_error_message_size, L"IdnToAscii finished with error");

    CString local_time_string = CTime::GetCurrentTime().FormatGmt("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S GMT");

    wsprintf((wchar_t*)local_error_message, L"Networking error -- %s -- %s\r\n", local_system_error_message, local_time_string.GetBuffer());

    //  В local_error_message находится текст с кодом сетевой ошибки при выполнении функции IdnToAscii

    return false;
  }

  PDNS_RECORD   ppQueryResults;

  ZeroMemory(&ppQueryResults, sizeof(ppQueryResults));

  if (DnsQuery_W(local_domain_name_unicode, DNS_TYPE_A, 0, NULL, &ppQueryResults, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    for (PDNS_RECORD ptr = ppQueryResults; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->pNext)
    {
      if (ptr->wType == DNS_TYPE_A)
      {
        if (ptr->wDataLength != 0)
        {
          char local_address_buffer[100];
          inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ptr->Data.A.IpAddress, local_address_buffer, 100);

          local_internet_name.push_back(local_address_buffer);
        }
      }
    }

    DnsFree(ppQueryResults, DnsFreeRecordList);

    if (local_internet_name.size() != 0)
    {
      return true;  //  Адреса найдены
    }
    else
    {
      return false; //  Адреса не найдены
    }

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

int main()
{
  std::list<CStringA> local_internet_name_6;
  if (domain_name_to_internet_6_name(CStringW(L"dns.google"), local_internet_name_6))
  {
    for (auto i = local_internet_name_6.begin(); i != local_internet_name_6.end(); i++)
    {
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
  }

  std::list<CStringA> local_internet_name_4;
  if (domain_name_to_internet_4_name(CStringW(L"dns.google"), local_internet_name_4))
  {
    for (auto i = local_internet_name_4.begin(); i != local_internet_name_4.end(); i++)
    {
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```